Update AppBarText in MudBlazor
I'm using MudBlazor to learn about the Blazor language. I have created a menu using MudAppBar.
MainLayout.razor
<MudThemeProvider />
<MudPopoverProvider />
<MudDialogProvider />
<MudSnackbarProvider />

<MudLayout>
    <MudAppBar Color="Color.Primary" Fixed="true">
        <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Menu" Color="Color.Inherit" Edge="Edge.Start" OnClick="DrawerToggle" />
        @appBarText
    </MudAppBar>
    <MudDrawer @bind-Open="@_drawerOpen" Anchor="Anchor.Left">
        <MudDrawerContainer>
            <MudNavMenu Bordered="true"> 
                <MudNavLink Href="" Match="NavLinkMatch.All" >Home</MudNavLink>
                <MudNavLink Href="/counter" >Counter</MudNavLink>
                <MudNavLink Href="fetchdata">FetchData</MudNavLink>
            </MudNavMenu>
        </MudDrawerContainer>
    </MudDrawer>
    <MudMainContent>
        <MudContainer MaxWidth="MaxWidth.ExtraLarge">
            @Body
        </MudContainer>
    </MudMainContent>
</MudLayout>

@code {
    bool _drawerOpen = true;
    private string appBarText = "Default AppBar Text";

    private void UpdateAppBarText(string text)
    {
        appBarText = text;
    }

    private void DrawerToggle()
    {
        _drawerOpen = !_drawerOpen;
    }
}


The problem I'm having is that I can't change "appBarText" to the link title when I click on MudNavLink.
I created the function "UpdateAppBarText" and assigned it to the OnClick event on MudNavLink but it failed. Can anyone help me figure out which solution is best? Thank you everyone for your interest.
<MudNavMenu Bordered="true"> 
    <MudNavLink Href="" Match="NavLinkMatch.All" OnClick="@(() => UpdateAppBarText("Home"))">Home</MudNavLink>
    <MudNavLink Href="/counter" OnClick="@(() => UpdateAppBarText("Counter"))">Counter</MudNavLink>
    <MudNavLink Href="/fetchdata" OnClick="@(()=> UpdateAppBarText("FetchData"))">FetchData</MudNavLink>
</MudNavMenu>


You can add a OnClick handler to the MudNavLink.  If you do, you need to handle the full navigation event in the handler.  You can do something like this:
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
@inject NavigationManager NavManager
<MudThemingProvider />
<MudPopoverProvider />
<MudDialogProvider />
<MudSnackbarProvider />

<MudLayout>
    <MudAppBar Color="Color.Primary" Fixed="true">
        <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Menu" Color="Color.Inherit" Edge="Edge.Start" OnClick="DrawerToggle" />
        @appBarText
    </MudAppBar>
    <MudDrawer @bind-Open="@_drawerOpen" Anchor="Anchor.Left">
        <MudDrawerContainer>
            <MudNavMenu Bordered="true">
                <MudNavLink OnClick="@((e) => OnLinkChanged("Home", "/"))" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">Home</MudNavLink>
                <MudNavLink OnClick="@((e) => OnLinkChanged("Counter", "counter"))">Counter</MudNavLink>
                <MudNavLink OnClick="@((e) => OnLinkChanged("Weather", "weather"))">Weather</MudNavLink>
            </MudNavMenu>
        </MudDrawerContainer>
    </MudDrawer>
    <MudMainContent>
        <MudContainer MaxWidth="MaxWidth.ExtraLarge">
            @Body
        </MudContainer>
    </MudMainContent>
</MudLayout>

@code {
    bool _drawerOpen = true;
    private string appBarText = "Default AppBar Text";

    private Task OnLinkChanged(string title, string url)
    {
        appBarText = title;
        NavManager.NavigateTo(url);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private void DrawerToggle()
    {
        _drawerOpen = !_drawerOpen;
    }
}


Thanks "MrC aka Shaun Curtis" for your support, I have updated the AppBarText according to your code. The current problem I'm having is that when I click on MudNavLink, the color of the link border is lost. Can you help me check this? Thank you.
